# Импорт переменной

Tags: python

test_1.py

```
class my_class ():
    """"""
    def amount (self):
        z = 1 + y
        print (z)
```

---

test_2.py

```
import test_1

select = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
number = test_1.my_class()

for y in select:
    amount = number.amount()
```

Как переменную `y` импортировать, чтобы она исполнилась при вызове функции `amount()`?

Comment: В Питоне  lexical binding для имён используется. Ваш пример пытается что-то подобное dynamic binding использовать (как к примеру в emacs lisp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто передать в метод

```
class my_class ():
    def amount (self,y):
        z = 1 + y
        print (z)
```

Вызвать можно так

```
for y in select:
    amount = number.amount(y)
```